# why does my window doesn't work for on_draw?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I was watching a video about pyglet and I tried to create a triangle:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

class mywindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(300,300)
        
window = mywindow(300,300,"deneme", True)

def on_draw():
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE)
    glColor3b(255,0,0)
    glVertex2f(-1,0)
    glColor3b(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(1,0)
    glColor3b(0,0,255)
    glVertex2f(0,1)

window.on_draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

when I run this code; I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'mywindow' object has no attribute 'on_draw'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_draw` has to be a method of the class `mywindow` rather than a function. Don't invoke `on_draw` yourself, because it is called automatically, when the window is needed to be updated.
At the begin of `on_draw` you've to clear the display by (see [Windowing](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/windowing.html)).
A OpenGL immediate mode `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence has to be ended by [`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml). The [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) type is `GL_TRIANGLES` rather than `GL_TRIANGLE`. If you want to specify the colors in range [0, 255], the you've to use [`glColor3ub`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) (unsigned byte) rather then `glColor3b` (signed byte).
You have to set the viewport rectangle of the resizable window by [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml) in the `on_resize` event.

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

class mywindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(300,300)

    def on_draw(self):

        self.clear()

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glColor3ub(255, 0, 0)
        glVertex2f(-1, 0)
        glColor3ub(0, 255, 0)
        glVertex2f(1, 0)
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 255)
        glVertex2f(0, 1)
        glEnd()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

window = mywindow(300,300,"deneme", True)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: from pyglet.gl import *
   ...:
   ...: window = pyglet.window.Window()
   ...:
   ...: vlist = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v2f', [0,0, 400,50, 200,300]))
   ...:
   ...: @window.event
   ...: def on_draw():
   ...:     glClear(pyglet.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
   ...:     glColor3f(1,0,0)
   ...:     vlist.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)
   ...:
   ...: pyglet.app.run()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not searching a working code. I am trying to understand what did I wrong.